# Tikz: Align Drop Line to left of box when single line of text is present in node

Tags: latex, tikz

I am playing with the example from Tikz located [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/work-breakdown-structure/). When I change the text from "Defining nodes and arrow styles" to "Defining nodes" the line dropping to the children of this node shifts to the right.

Is there a way to make the line always be set to the left of the box surrounding "Defining node" like when there are two lines of text?

[image: Example of Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to making sure the trailing lines were always to one side of the next level, in this case forcing the line to shift to the left of the "Defining node" block, is simply a switch from

```
c1.195
```

to

```
c1.west
```

in the \foreach statements seen in the example of the original post.